# Have any guide to implement ActiveMQ with Cocoa Application?

Tags: cocoa, jms, message, activemq-classic, stomp

I've found `ActiveMQ` that use for message broker and that's good for cross-platform

Have any guide to implement `ActiveMQ` Consumers (Client) in Cocoa Application ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use ActiveMQ-CPP and then do some research on using C++ from Objective-C, seems like there's some extensions that allow that.  Or you can quickly write a little Stomp client in Objective-C for you app.